# Split GST Command using Shell Script

Tags: string, shell, split, gstreamer

I'd like to split the following GST command into two halves using shell script.

`/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0KAHukBQHpCAAAH0AAB1MAI\\,aM48gA\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)2416890621, clock-base=(uint)518578781, seqnum-base=(uint)24075`

The split has to occur at caps =
The two new lines should be stored in two variables $var1 and $var2

$var1 should contain
`/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink:`

And $var2 should contain
`application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0KAHukBQHpCAAAH0AAB1MAI\\,aM48gA\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)2416890621, clock-base=(uint)518578781, seqnum-base=(uint)24075`

Remember there are two backslashes in the input string. So doing an echo will give only one backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ cmd='/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0KAHukBQHpCAAAH0AAB1MAI\\,aM48gA\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)2416890621, clock-base=(uint)518578781, seqnum-base=(uint)24075'

$ first=${cmd% caps = *}; echo ">>$first<<"
>>/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink:<<

$ second=${cmd#* caps = }; echo ">>$second<<"
>>application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0KAHukBQHpCAAAH0AAB1MAI\\,aM48gA\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)2416890621, clock-base=(uint)518578781, seqnum-base=(uint)24075<<
```

Comment: When I do an echo, it changes the two backslashes to one backslash. How do I fix this? echo -e also gives me a single backslash.

Comment: make sure you use double quotes around the variable in the echo command. My output above was copy/pasted and the backslashes seem consistent.

Answer (score 1):

```
a="/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0KAHukBQHpCAAAH0AAB1MAI\\,aM48gA\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)2416890621, clock-base=(uint)518578781, seqnum-base=(uint)24075"
```

You could cut strings by **spaces**.

```
var1=`echo $a | cut -d' ' -f1` 

$var1 = /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink:

var2=`echo $a | cut -d' ' -f4-` 

$var2 = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0KAHukBQHpCAAAH0AAB1MAI\\,aM48gA\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)2416890621, clock-base=(uint)518578781, seqnum-base=(uint)24075
```

Comment: When I do an echo, it changes the two backslashes to one backslash. How do I fix this? echo -e also gives me a single backslash.